# Python Fabric Prompt Not Storing Var

Tags: python, while-loop, fabric

Strange problem here. If I use `fabric.operations.prompt` to get the value of a variable, it appears to store it just fine. However, it's confusing my while loop.

Here is the code setting the variable manually:

```
def test():
    #var1 = fabric.operations.prompt("Var1:")
    var1 = 3
    var2 = 1
    while (var1 > var2):
        print("hi")
        var2 = var2 + 1
        print("var2: %s" % var2)
        print("var1: %s" % var1)
```

Not surprisingly, the output is:

```
[me@host]$ fab test
hi
var2: 2
var1: 3
hi
var2: 3
var1: 3

Done.
```

However, if I change my code to be:

```
def test():
    var1 = fabric.operations.prompt("Var1:")
    var2 = 1
    while (var1 > var2):
        print("hi")
        var2 = var2 + 1
        print("var2: %s" % var2)
        print("var1: %s" % var1)
```

The output is something like the below. Caught it as soon as I could, it executed extremely fast.

```
var1: 3
hi
var2: 34567
var1: 3
hi
var2: 34568
var1: 3
hi
var2: 34569
var1: 3
hi
var2: 34570
^C
Stopped.
```

This loop is telling me that `3 > 34570`. That's not true. I think this is fabric-specific and something with the `.prompt` operation.

This has to be a variable, I can't set it manually.

Comment: [`fabric.operations.prompt`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.prompt) probably returns a string and not an int. Comparing a `str` and an `int` does some [pretty weird things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) in Python 2.

Comment: That was it, thanks!